# Is there any data transfer limit for Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, java, mysql, raid, tomcat

I have developed a web application with Java which is deployed to tomcat and uses mysql as database. These softwares run on either in my developer computer which is Ubuntu 18.04 or in a server which is also Ubuntu 18.04. All softwares are identical to each other according to version and configurations.

Somehow, when I send POST/PUT request to the web application if the request is long, the server doesn't get payload properly and throws exception like [mentioned exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393743/what-may-be-the-reason-of-unexpected-end-of-input-in-value-string-error). If I send the same request to the developer computer everything works fine. I crosschecked it by using a third computer which is also Ubuntu 18.04(xubuntu flavor), everything works fine in that computer too.

So as I think, the problem is about not tomcat or mysql or my application but Ubuntu. Maybe there is a limit which must be configured but misconfigured, or maybe I made some mistakes when I installed Ubuntu.

By the way, differences between server and other system is that server has RAID support and ECC RAM. I don't think these will affect but you may have better information about it.

**EDIT**

*Developer Comp.*

- 12GB RAM
- Intel® Core™ i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4(64Bit)
- 1TB SSD
- Ubuntu 18.04

*Server*

- 16GB ECC RAM
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) W-2125 CPU @ 4.00GHz
- 512GB+512GB M.2 SSD
- Dual Boot Win10+Ubuntu 18.04(Just this is used)
- RAID 1

**EDIT 2**

I started to think that RAID may cause this. Normally dual boot is in the system, but I am not able to start Win10. So there may be a problem with that SSD. In addition one of SSD is NTFS(Win10), other is ext4(Ubuntu), this may affect RAID.

**EDIT3**

I noticed that firefox browser shows that unsuccessful requests have ~600B data transferred. Normal size of data must be ~70MB. Surprisingly, in constrast, it seems that server had successfully get data either from successful or unsuccessful requests.

[Screenshot from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWdfC.png)

[Screenshot from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbuVe.png)

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! The non-GUI parts of Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop and Xubuntu of the same release (18.04) should be identical. There should also be no software limitations… However, does your server use hardware that is different from your other machines? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question.

Comment: is it the same database with the same amount of data? btw it is NOT a good idea to have the db on the same server as your web application. another thing that comes to mind is ulimit. if your prod server has a lot of connections, you might wnat to check that the system users are allowed to have appropriate ressources.

Comment: Yes, same db version, same amount of data. Altough web application and db is seperated, result is same. Actually if I use server just for mysql and use developer computer as web server, no problem occurs, vice versa same problem stays. There is no problem with user/connection count and allowence to have appropriate resources.